# Add an autocomplete widget with compile SDK 19 android

Tags: android, autocomplete

i want to have  an autocomplete widget in my android app 
like the examples here :https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget 
i tried all examples but  they all used SDK 23 my app for some reasons need to use SDK version 19  any example for using autocomplete widget with ir

Comment: Have you seen this? Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: i need something like this https://developers.google.com/places/images/acw_overlay.png

Comment: Can you explain what are you looking for exactly? An autocomplete dialog that would show suggestions from within your app? Or the one that seaches the internet, or something like that...?

Comment: i want to add places autocoplete widget it searches google places for an adress and return with latlng object so i can use it in my whole app